# Input chunks paths in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, input

I have a Hadoop setup running on 16 VM's each 4 processors.
Main input file is divided into small chunks (InputSlit) and distributed to different machines.
Now how do i find the which part of the input and its replicas is residing on which machine?
Is there any command?
I did not find much information on internet.
Thanks in advance

Pavan kumar Alluri

Comment: Why would you want to do the work that namenode does for you? Just leave it with the framework..

Comment: I am just curious to know if there is any command to see the input chunks on different machines

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to compute a distribution of your data over machines:

```
    Path file = new Path("/path/to/some/file/");
    FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(getConf());
    FileStatus fileStatus = fs.getFileStatus(file);
    HDFSBlocksDistribution dist = FSHDFSUtils.computeHDFSBlocksDistribution(fs, fileStatus, 0, fileStatus.getLen());
    for (HDFSBlocksDistribution.HostAndWeight value : dist.getHostAndWeights().values()) {
        System.out.println(value.getHost() + "\t" + value.getWeight());
    }
```